# Standard notation for rowwise subtraction

Tags: matrices, notation

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, how do I concisely denote the subtraction of a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ from each of its rows?

Comment: By $A=(v_1,\ldots ,v_n)$ and $B=(v_1-v,\ldots ,v_n-v)$ with row vectors $v_1,\ldots ,v_n$.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of $\mathbb{1} = (1_1, \dots, 1_n)$:
$$\mathbf{A}^{'} = \mathbf{A}-\mathbb{1}^{\top}v$$.